# How should I add multiple google street-view in react?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I added three street-views in one component using `Google street view component for React.js` called `react-streetview` and got error :
[image]
Here's a component's code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactStreetview from 'react-streetview'
import { streetViewPanoramaOptions } from './constants.js'

const About = () => {
  const googleMapsApiKey = 'myAPIkey'    
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        style={{ .... }}
      >
        <ReactStreetview
          apiKey={googleMapsApiKey}
          streetViewPanoramaOptions={streetViewPanoramaOptions.hall}
        />
      </div>
      <div
        style={{ .... }}
      >
        <ReactStreetview
          apiKey={googleMapsApiKey}
          streetViewPanoramaOptions={streetViewPanoramaOptions.firstRoom}
        />
      </div>
      <div
        style={{ .... }}
      >
        <ReactStreetview
          apiKey={googleMapsApiKey}
          streetViewPanoramaOptions={streetViewPanoramaOptions.secondRoom}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default About
```

Comment: Maybe because you're using multiple `ReactStreetview`s. It seems that each time you use the component the Google Maps API is loaded in.

Comment: I understand that, andwould be happy to know How do I solve my problem?

Comment: Seems like you'll want to write your own custom ReactStreetview component that doesn't pull in its own version of Maps, and rely on a single API that connects to multiple view instances.